# Node.js Returns Cannot Read Property disabled of undefined when detect a post request with server.on

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

In Node Js I have an application where i want to add a cookie when the user should be disabled from the site.

login.js

```
app.post('/login/check' (req, res) => {
//check username password and other stuff
// if invalid credentials make increase pass_enter_tries by 1
if (parseInt(req.cookies.pass_enter_tries) >= 5) {
  res.cookie('disabled', 'true', {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1800000),
    signed: true
  });
```

This works fine, when the user enter 5 incorrect passwords, they get disabled. But the real problem is when i detect the disabled.

app.js

```
const http = require('http')
, express = require('express')
, app = express()
, server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080);

require('./login')(app);

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  if (req.signedCookies.disabled == 'true') {
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/disabled.html');
  }
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});
```

When The user posts to /login/check, even if they enter correct credentials, the console logs:

> if (req.signedCookies.disabled == 'true') {
>                        ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined

How do i make it just return req.signedCookies.disabled = undefined rather than it throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.signedCookies` is a property of express request object. Not the `http.IncomingMessage` which is the `req` parameter of `request` event.

You should use a express middleware instead of `server.on('request'...)` block:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.signedCookies.disabled == 'true') {
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/disabled.html');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

require('./login')(app);
```

**Note**: You should use the middlware ABOVE any of the routes.